Does boost::span work correctly with boost::begin?
I'm using Boost 1.78, and I'm trying to use its implementation of std::span.  While the span implementation seems to be fine, when I call boost::begin() on a span, if that span is an rvalue, it returns a const pointer, which breaks important use cases like:
   boost::fill( returns_a_span(), 0 );

A test program (which won't compile - it's the error messages that are interesting) is:
#include <vector>
#include <boost/core/span.hpp>
#include <boost/range/begin.hpp>

template <typename T>
struct ErrorType;

int main() {

   std::vector<unsigned char> vec{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
   boost::span<unsigned char> sp{ vec };

   ErrorType< decltype( std::begin(sp) ) > e1;
   ErrorType< decltype( std::begin(std::move(sp)) ) > e2;
   ErrorType< decltype( boost::begin(sp) ) > e3;
   ErrorType< decltype( boost::begin(std::move(sp)) ) > e4;
   ErrorType< decltype( sp.begin() ) > e5;
   ErrorType< decltype( std::move(sp).begin() ) > e6;

   return 0;
}

The output of the compiler is:
spantest.cc: In function int main():
spantest.cc:13:44: error: aggregate ErrorType<unsigned char*> e1 has incomplete type and cannot be defined
    ErrorType< decltype( std::begin(sp) ) > e1;
                                            ^~
spantest.cc:14:55: error: aggregate ErrorType<unsigned char*> e2 has incomplete type and cannot be defined
    ErrorType< decltype( std::begin(std::move(sp)) ) > e2;
                                                       ^~
spantest.cc:15:46: error: aggregate ErrorType<unsigned char*> e3 has incomplete type and cannot be defined
    ErrorType< decltype( boost::begin(sp) ) > e3;
                                              ^~
spantest.cc:16:57: error: aggregate ErrorType<const unsigned char*> e4 has incomplete type and cannot be defined
    ErrorType< decltype( boost::begin(std::move(sp)) ) > e4;
                                                         ^~
spantest.cc:17:40: error: aggregate ErrorType<unsigned char*> e5 has incomplete type and cannot be defined
    ErrorType< decltype( sp.begin() ) > e5;
                                        ^~
spantest.cc:18:51: error: aggregate ErrorType<unsigned char*> e6 has incomplete type and cannot be defined
    ErrorType< decltype( std::move(sp).begin() ) > e6;


The fact that the types are incomplete is expected - I'm just using it as a way of getting the compiler to tell me what the types are.  The interesting one is e4 - boost::begin() on an rvalue span returns a const pointer, even though the method doesn't (e6) and std::begin() doesn't (e2).  Is this just a bug in boost::begin(), or do I misunderstand something?  Is there a workaround other than always using an lvalue?
It looks like this question is closely related to std::begin and R-values, but std::begin() no longer seems to have the issue, but boost::begin() does.  The boost range algorithms, however, explicitly call boost::begin(), so they seem to not work well with spans of non-const data.
I understand that if boost::begin() gets called with an rvalue and no rvalue overload exists that it could use a const lvalue reference.  What I don't understand is why boost::span is different than any other iterator range - boost range algorithms are passed rvalue ranges all the time, but I've never seen this before.

Looks like the whole issue is you're instantiating incomplete ErrorType instances.
Let's rename it E for brevity and actually define it!
template <typename> struct E{};

Now everything compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/E78qh8c75
#include <boost/core/span.hpp>
#include <boost/range/begin.hpp>
#include <vector>

template <typename> struct E{};

int main() {
    std::vector<unsigned char> vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    boost::span<unsigned char>   sp{vec};

    E<decltype(std::begin(sp))>              e1;
    E<decltype(std::begin(std::move(sp)))>   e2;
    E<decltype(boost::begin(sp))>            e3;
    E<decltype(boost::begin(std::move(sp)))> e4;
    E<decltype(sp.begin())>                  e5;
    E<decltype(std::move(sp).begin())>       e6;
}

Looking at boost::fill
Comparing notes shows that the problem is with boost::fill, not boost::span:
Live On 1.84 or 1.78
#include <boost/core/span.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/fill.hpp>
#include <boost/range/begin.hpp>
#include <cstdint>
#include <ranges>
#include <span>
#include <vector>

template <typename...> struct E {};

auto returns_boost_span() {
    static std::vector<uint8_t> vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    return boost::span<uint8_t>(vec);
}

auto returns_std_span() {
    static std::vector<uint8_t> vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    return std::span<uint8_t>(vec);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<unsigned char> vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    boost::span<unsigned char> bsp{vec};

    [[maybe_unused]] E<decltype(std::begin(bsp)), decltype(std::begin(std::move(bsp))),
                       decltype(boost::begin(bsp)), decltype(boost::begin(std::move(bsp))),
                       decltype(bsp.begin()), decltype(std::move(bsp).begin())>
                             be;
    std::span<unsigned char> ssp{vec};

    [[maybe_unused]] E<decltype(std::begin(ssp)), decltype(std::begin(std::move(ssp))),
                       decltype(boost::begin(ssp)), decltype(boost::begin(std::move(ssp))),
                       decltype(ssp.begin()), decltype(std::move(ssp).begin())>
        se;

    {
        auto s = returns_boost_span();
        boost::fill(s, 0);
        // boost::fill(returns_boost_span(), 0); // DOESN'T COMPILE
    }

    {
        auto s = returns_std_span();
        boost::fill(s, 0);
        // boost::fill(returns_std_span(), 0); // ALSO DOESN'T COMPILE
        std::ranges::fill(s, 0);
        std::ranges::fill(returns_std_span(), 0);
    }
}


That ErrorType was incomplete was intentional - I was after the error messages that showed the exact return types of boost::begin().  Both boost::begin and boost::fill have overloads for lvalue ref and const lvalue ref ranges but not rvalue ranges, so if you pass them rvalue ranges, you get the const version with const iterators.  This would make sense for ranges that contain their data, but no so much for proxy objects like span.  My current workaround is to write overloads of boost::begin/end for boost::span that return non-const iterators for const and rvalue spans.  Is there a better way?

I think the better way is to report as a defect at Boost Range (citing Boost Core span as the example). They will possibly end up adding the same fix, but potentially they do something more structural to support proxy types in general

Also, I'm using C++14, which is why I'm trying to do this with boost and not std::span/ranges.

I was hoping the comparison with std::span and more importantly std::ranges::fill might shed light on where the problem is, exactly.
